# Scala: Creating Options from Seq/Tuple and add to a Sequence

Tags: scala

Edit:

Suppose I have a Seq:

```
Seq(Some("Earth"),Some("Mars"))
```

I need to add few more elements at start of this sequence. Values to be added are generated based on an Option value.
So I try to do as:

```
 val o = ....//Option calculated here
 Seq(o.map(myFunction(_)),"Earth","Mars")

 def myFunction(s: String) = s match {
     case "x" => Seq(Some("Jupiter"), Some("Venus"))
     case "y"  => Seq(Some("PLuto"), Some("Mercury"))
 }
```

But map would give me Some(Seq(.....)).

Comment: Can you show us what have you done ?

Comment: So supposing the **Option** was a `Some` then you want to prepend all the elements returned by `myFunction` if it was a `None` then nothing should be added, right?

Comment: Yes, thats what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of problem I recommend checking the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) and following a technique called [**type-tetris**](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2017/04/11/type-tetris.html).

You need this:

```scala
def prependIfDefined(data: Option[A], previousElements: Seq[Option[B]]): Seq[Option[B]] =
  data.fold(ifEmpty = Seq.empty[Option[B]])(getNewData) ++ previousElements

def getNewData(a: A): Seq[Option[B]] = ???
```